# How do I use LINQ to access a specific value from of an array of JObjects that seems to be stored in a string

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm making a database call in C# that looks something like this:

```
public JArray GetEmployeeInfo(string search_text)
{
    var search = search_text.Split(' ');

    var dataObject = _db.Employee
        .Where(x => x.Usage.Equals("basic") &&
                    search.All(s => x.EmployeeName.Contains(s) || 
                                    x.EmployeeEmailAddress.Contains(s) || 
                                    x.EmployeeId.Contains(s)))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.EmployeeId,
            x.EmployeeName,
            x.EmployeeEmailAddress,
            x.EmployeeDepartmentName,
            x.UsageTags
        });

    return JArray.FromObject(dataObject);
}
```

Which works fine. The issue is the format of the data that's being returned. It looks something like this:

```
{
  "EmployeeId": "000012345",
  "EmployeeName": "Firstname Lastname",
  "EmployeeEmailAddress": "flastname1@website.com",
  "EmployeeDepartmentName": "Accounting",
  "EmployeeType": "Staff",
  "UsageTags": "[{\"seqNo\":1,\"Tag\":\"CurrentEmpl:Accountant\"},{\"seqNo\":2,\"Tag\":\"CurrentEmpl:Manager\"},{\"seqNo\":3,\"Tag\":\"Intern:Attended\"}]"
}
```

and what I need is to have `UsageTags` be an array of the `Tag` values, like this:

```
{
  "EmployeeId": "000012345",
  "EmployeeName": "Firstname Lastname",
  "EmployeeEmailAddress": "flastname1@website.com",
  "EmployeeDepartmentName": "Accounting",
  "EmployeeType": "Staff",
  "UsageTags": ["CurrentEmpl:Accountant", "CurrentEmpl:Manager", "Intern:Attended"]
}
```

Right now, I'm formatting it in JavaScript, but it would be a lot better if I could just write out a LINQ statement that does it on the server side. I wasted most of today trying different solutions from here, along with Google and my old C# Cookbook, but nothing seems to do the trick.

Anyone have a solution that would somehow parse the `UsageTags` into an array of `JObjects`, then pull out the values of all the `Tag` keys and toss the values in an array? Because, I am going crazy banging my head against this one.

Comment: What about `x.UsageTags.Select(u => u.Tag)` instead of `x.UsageTags` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `UsageTags` is a string already containing JSON, so you'll need to deserialize it in each item so that you can extract the tag names.

Try something like this:

```
public JArray GetEmployeeInfo(string search_text)
{
    var search = search_text.Split(' ');

    var dataObject = _db.Employee
        .Where(x => x.Usage.Equals("basic") && 
                    search.All(s => x.EmployeeName.Contains(s) || 
                                    x.EmployeeEmailAddress.Contains(s) || 
                                    x.EmployeeId.Contains(s)))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.EmployeeId,
            x.EmployeeName,
            x.EmployeeEmailAddress,
            x.EmployeeDepartmentName,
            x.UsageTags
        })
        .ToList();    // materialize the database query

    var array = new JArray(
        dataObject.Select(o =>
        {
            var jo = JObject.FromObject(o);
            // parse and transform the UsageTags
            jo["UsageTags"] = new JArray(
                JArray.Parse((string)jo["UsageTags"])
                      .Select(jt => jt["Tag"])
            );
            return jo;
        })
    );

    return array;
}
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nbHbkZ

Comment: This is not only a clean solution, but an elegant one.
It worked perfectly on the first try. Thank you, sir!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!